# Laravel permissions pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, permissions, laravel-permission

I am making **custom permissions**,

I would like them to be divided into sections e.g. orders, customers etc. and each section would have some permission e.g. edit, delete, add.
Just to check if a particular user has access I would have to start with the Section model?

Because I can't do something like `Auth::user()->permissions()->with('sections')->contains('name','display')->contains('sections','order')`

I would like to simply check if the user has access to, for example, `order.display`.
I have a feeling that this section does not make sense here.

How to do it? I know there is a spatie(laravel-permission), but there is a role division there.

Example schema of the database (user_permission is a pivot):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My advice is if you're looking for something simple, drop the sections table and just have all permissions in the `permissions` table. Say you had a section called `dashboard` in permissions you could have `view_dashboard` `edit_dashboard` etc. Then to check the user is authorised, implement the `hasManyThrough` logic below [Official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through)

(untested)

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Permissions::class, UserPermissions::class);
}

public function permission_check($permission_to_check)
{
    return $this->permissions->contains($permission_to_check);
}
```

You could then eager load `permissions()` on the user model to reduce DB queries if you are checking permission in many places.

Hope this helps, let me know if I can assist further :)

Comment: Quite simple, however I do not need UserPermissions model due to its a pivot